# Cannot scrape a subpage through scrapy inside a for loop, do i miss something here?

Tags: python, scrapy, nested

i am trying to scrape with scrapy first the main page and then from a subpage.
Here i am scraping well information mentioned in the def.parse, but cannot make the spider go to one suburl, grab more info and then add everything into one element from dictionary d.
Can you help? (Sorry i am a newbie in python and scrapy,i read the tutorial but coudn't figure it out)
Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from datetime import datetime,time
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('192.168.X.XXXX',32768)
db = client.ABC 
collection = db.abc




shopref='9000'

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "some_name"

    
    start_urls = [
        
         'https:'one_url'+str(shopref),
                 ]
        

    def parse(self, response):
        
        for y in response.css('div.wrapper'):

            d={}
            
            d['abcdef'] = 'information i need'
            .....
            url_i_need = 'url i need to scrape to add information to dictionnary d'  
            
            
            yield from response.follow_all(url_i_need,callback=self.parsedetails)
            
                   
            

        next_page = response.css('li.pagination-next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = 'url to follow'
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
    
   
    def parsedetails(self,response):

        d['klm'] = 'information i need in the subpage in my dictionary d'
    

       

if __name__=="__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()
```

Comment: Which tutorial did you read?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: Ok great, I was just confused why you'd decided to use `CrawlerProcess` and so on as a beginner (which isn't featured in the tutorial). Have a look [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) to see how to pass information to callbacks.